# Can we use different CSS language/pre processors for different components in a Angular Project

Tags: css, angular, sass

Suppose their are three Developers working on a same angular  Project, each one of them is developing a different component, but during the initialization 'scss' is set as preferred styling language, but now one developer want to use stylus instead of 'scss' but the others are comfortable with 'scss'.

So is it possible to use different style language for different components in a angular project.

Answer (score 2):

This will work. You can use [sass/scss, less and stylus](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors).

Just use the style preprocessor you want for the component you're working on. An example:

`less-example.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'less-example',
  styleUrls: [
    './less-example.less'
  ],
  templateUrl: './less-example.component.html'
})
export class LessExample {

}
```

`less-example.less`

```
@color: yellow;

h1 {
  color: @color;
}
```

`scss-example.component.ts`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'scss-example',
  templateUrl: './scss-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './scss-example.scss'
  ]
})
export class ScssExample {

}
```

`scss-example.scss`

```
  $color: green;

  h1 {
    color: $color;
  }
```

You can see this in action [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sa94rd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fscss_comp%2Fscss-example.scss)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can [generate component options](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component)

you can do so by add `--styleext=[file extension]` like so `ng g c test --styleext=scss` you can do that for each component you generate just specify `--styleext option` with pre-processor you want to use.